# Facebook group page: add poll options AND a photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Via the Facebook Graph API:

Can I ask a question within a Facebook Group (e.g. 'Do you like scones Devon-style or Cornwall style?') and accompany that question with a photo (e.g. a bunch of scones, some with cream then jam, some with jam then cream).

Comment: do you mean when publishing to a Group or to a Page?

Comment: @Si - to a group http://www.facebook.com/PlatterHQ?fref=ts

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/